# How to find an ssh session a process was started from

Tags: ssh, find, process, session

How can I find a process which was started from some ssh session.

For instance, I gave same ssh cridentials (aka. userzxc/passwordzxc) for my several friends which IPs i already know.

My goal is to find out the link between the special ssh session and some running/started process to control who could bring down/crash/destroy/etc. services on my machine.

1. Maybe there are apps/services for that
2. Or maybe there are several commands to make it happen

Thank you.

Comment: What about `pstree -lnu | less` or `pstree -lnupa | less` ? Look for sshd ot for user names in their output.

Comment: @skwllsp cool, I will dig that way :) thanks. p.s. i need to also output ssh client ip information insteard of PIDs of sshd :)

Comment: `sudo lsof -i` will tell you which PIDs are connecting to what network addresses.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
pstree -lnu | less
```

or

```
pstree -lnupa | less
```

Look for `sshd` or for username in their output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add special user and group for each of your friends
2. Use [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/) with Permissive mode

Answer (score 0):

Each user should have their own credentials, so it's just a matter of displaying all the processes of a given user. If you have a process ID, you can know which user started it by running `ps -Af` and looking in the “USER” column (many other combinations of options will list this information, check the `ps` man page on your system). Given a user `bob`, `ps -u bob` will list all of that user's processes. If you want to see what processes are running on your system, [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) is a convenient interactive process explorer.

The command [`who`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/who.1.html) lists active sessions. For SSH sessions, it lists the original IP address. You can find more information in the system logs (the location depends on your distribution, for example `/var/log/auth.log` on Debian with SysVinit). The commands [`last`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html) and [`lastcomm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lastcomm.1.html) (part of the `acct` package, often not installed by default) provide some information about past sessions.